# C program scheduler; how to use SetProcessAfinityMask() to assign process to specific CPU #

Tags: c, windows, scheduler, bitmask, createprocess

I *did indeed* research through google and old stack overflow posts, but was still having trouble conceptually trying to figure out the steps I need to program, and I always get great help from Stack Overflow, so figured I would utilize your great help :D

I am writing a simple C "scheduler" program that implements a **First Come First Serve** (FCFS) algorithm. You run the executable of the .c program, in this case let's call it "scheduler.exe" and you can pass a list of arguments that are interpreted as *SECONDS...*, like this:
[image]

So in this image, I am calling the "scheduler" program and passing the command line arguments "6 12 4 5 10", which are a **list of positive integer values**. The integer values are execution times for instances of the program computeProgram_64.exe (another program provided to us by our Professor). So the argv[] array should have the name of the program in argv[0] (in this case, "scheduler") and the arguments "6 12 4 5 10" in argv[1 ] to argv[5] (respectively).

The *1st step* is to call call the **GetCurrentProcess()** function which gives the scheduler a handle to itself. I did this via the code:

> HANDLE myProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

Then, the *2nd step* is to use the **GetProcessAffinityMask()** function to ask the operating system which processors are being made available to it, and pass the **HANDLE myProcess** from above code to **GetProcessAffinityMask()**, so that the operating system knows which process you want the affinity mask of. I did this via the code:

> // a memory location that can hold a value
>
> DWORD_PTR lpProcessAffinityMask = 0;
>
> // a memory location that can hold a value
>
> DWORD_PTR lpSystemAffinityMask = 0;
>
> BOOL res = GetProcessAffinityMask(myProcess, &lpProcessAffinityMask,
>   &lpSystemAffinityMask);

I used the printf statements below to check the values of lpProcessAffinityMask, which output to 0xFFF in HEX, and 4095 in decimal (base 10). I have a Intel 5820k, which has 6 cores but 12 threads, and 0xFFF is 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 in binary, so that looked correct as a bitmask of #12 cores (counting the number of '1' bits in the vector), i.e. an AffinityMask of 00000000000000000000000010011001 would imply only CPU0, CPU3, CPU4, and CPU7 are available per my understanding!

> printf("%d 0x%X\n",res,lpProcessAffinityMask);
>
> printf("\n"); printf("The GetProcessAffinityMask() returns a boolean
>   value of: %d\n", res);
>
> printf("The AffinityMask hex value is: 0x%X, decimal value is: %d\n",lpProcessAffinityMask,lpProcessAffinityMask);
>
> char *binaryString; binaryString = decimal_to_binary(lpProcessAffinityMask); printf("Which is equal to: %s in binary(32 bits)\n", binaryString);

**So now is where I was having trouble**, when I call **SetProcessAffinityMask()**, I need to make sure that I have exactly one bit set in the bitmask, that is, the bit that represents the CPU that I am assigning a process to. For finding the bits set in processAffinityMask, my Professor recommmend we use the C bitwise operators & and <<.

**However,** I wrote a decimal_to_binary(int n) function that takes the decimal output of the affinityMask and returns the binary answer stored in a char * pointer. I am not sure if I over complicated it doing this, but I figured I could then iterate (for loop) through the char array and then find the index of the specific available CPUs to allocate to the **SetProcessAffinityMask()**.

I am just confused at this point as to what I am doing with the command line arguments in argv[] array that holds the seconds "6 12 4 5 10", as they are supposed to be allocated in-order to the available CPUs returned by the AffinityMask of **GetProcessAffinityMask()**. Then I need to set the bit of the SetProcessAfinityMask() and then later start calling the processes via the **CreateProcess()** function.

Sorry if this is a long post, but I felt I had to explain some of the procedure. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what your actual question is. Your question is quite long and rambly, you might consider removing most of the story and just ask the question directly. Do you not know how to set a single bit in a variable? `DWORD v = 0; v |= (1 << (cpunum-1));`

Comment: You say a lot about what you need to do, but nothing about what you have done. Please share the code you have written, and please ask a specific question beyond "I am confused".